# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not re.Pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to extract data from text using regular expressions. I want to loop through the regular expression 'options' and then write the outcome to a specific list.

I think that I may not be writing my loop, and referencing the lists correctly. I get an error on line 27 stating: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not re.Pattern`. I have tried to put the regexlist into range(), but i then get this error: `TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer` on line 18 this time. I'm not sure on how to get around this?

*Please see my code below:*

```
import re

regexcode0 = re.compile(r'Test 0')
regexcode1 = re.compile(r'Test 1')
regexcode2 = re.compile(r'Test 2')

results_Test0 = []
results_Test1 = []
results_Test2 = []

allResults = [results_Test0, results_Test1, results_Test2]
regexlist = [regexcode0, regexcode1, regexcode2]

textBody = 'Hi there, Test 2 was a failure'

def text_extract(text):
    for i in regexlist:
        match = re.search(i, text)
        if match:
            matchObj = match.group()
            allResults[i].append(matchObj)

        if not match:
            allResults[i].append('No Solution')

    return allResults

print(text_extract(textBody))
```

I want the results to look like this:

```
results_Test0 = ['No Solution']
results_Test1 = ['No Solution']
results_Test2 = ['Test 2']
```

Comment: Why are you using regex with fixed strings? These are just examples, right? BTW welcome to SO! Check out [ask] if you want advice.

Comment: BTW parallel lists are usually bad practice in my experience. You'll probably want to use a dict instead, maybe with regex:result pairs.

Comment: Hi wjandrea - Yes these are just examples! Thank you for editing my question, it was the first I have asked. Also thank you for the advice on the parallel lists. I will incorporate it going forward.

Answer (score 1):

The type of `results_Testn` is `list`. The syntax of `list[index]` requires an integer to indicate a specific postition in the list. You are attempting to use `i` as an index, and its type is not integer, so that results in the error. If you want an integer for each iteration of the for loop, you can use the `enumerate` function:

```py
for index, i in enumerate(regexlist):
   #do something
```

In this example, `i` represents the re pattern and `index` is the number representing its position in the list, so you can use `allresults[index]` to save the result.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I will try to fix!